# Must I add adView.loadAd(new AdRequest()); to show Admob ad?

Tags: android

The following code from a sample app, it works well, I find the Admob still can be displayed even if I delete  AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adViewabout) and loadAd(new AdRequest()).

Why? Thanks!

```
public class AboutActivity  extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.about);     

        TextView mLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMyLink);
        mLink.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

        // Look up the AdView as a resource and load a request.
        AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adViewabout);
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());

    }
}


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"   
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="3dip"
    android:background="@drawable/border_ui"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/appversion"
        android:paddingLeft="7dip"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="7dip"
        android:text="V1.04" />

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/myabout"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dip"
        android:paddingLeft="7dip"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMyLink"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dip"
        android:paddingLeft="7dip"
        android:text="@string/mylink" />

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adViewabout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="a151bc26cd3bc22"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvOnlyTake"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dip"   
        android:layout_weight="1"     
        android:text="" />

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnClose"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        style="@style/myTextAppearance"
        android:text="@string/myreturn" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you already created the adRequest in XML

If you want to load the ad on specific time, or reload the ad on event, you can still use loadAd(new AdRequest())

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be because your layout xml says `ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"`